# How do I create an instance of a generic type?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I know this question has been asked before but  I haven't been able to solve it yet.

I am trying to create an instance of a class through a generic type.

I've tried this:

```
Class<VH>::getConstructor.call(parameter).newInstance()
```

But, I get this error: `I get this error for this method: Callable expects 2 arguments, but 1 were provided.`

I've also tried this method:

```
inline fun <reified VH> create(): VH {
         return  VH::class.java.newInstance()
     }
```

However, I haven't been able to call it because I can't use a generic type as a reified type.

This approach also doesn't work:

```
fun <VH> generateClass(type: Class<VH>): VH {
        return type.newInstance()
     }
```

As when I call it like this: `generateClass<VH>(Class<VH>::class.java)` I get this error: `Only classes are allowed on the left handside of a class literal`.

**My question in a nutshell**: How do I create an instance of a class from a generic type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see why your approach with `inline fun <reified VH> create(): VH` didn't work,
 for me it works,
please [see the demo](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/9h36f6pnj3js65flvumfancg5d/3eh1f132dgfe10natltilotmfk).

Comment: UPD: `inline fun <reified VH> create(): VH` will work only if you call it with a real type or a reified type parameter of an inline function. You can't call it with a non-reified type parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In your example you call the function like this: `create<MyClass>` and pass in `MyClass` as a concrete type. Whereas I need it work like this: `create<VH>` where VH is a generic type not an actual class.

Comment: A generic type has no type information to it, which you actually need to create an instance. You will have to manually supply that information. There are different solutions based on how you get `VH`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just posted an answer on how to instantiate a reified generic type using reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is using reflection and a reified generic type.

Firstly, make sure that the method that takes takes VH as a parameter is an inline function. Once you have a reified version of the generic type you can get its class name.

Once you have its class name you can instantiate it using reflection.

Here's how you get the class's name:

```
inline fun <reified VH: CustomClass> myMethod()  {

     //Make sure you use the qualifiedName otherwise the reflective call won't find the class
     val className VH::class.qualifiedName!!
 }
```

Here's how you instantiate the class:

`Class.forName(className).newInstance(constructorData) as VH`

**Note**: If the class is an inner class then you will get a classnotfoundexception unless you replace the dot before the inner class's name with a `$` symbol.

Here's an example:

`com.example.package.outerClass.innnerClass` - This will throw the classnotfoundexception

`com.example.package.outerClass$innnerClass` - This will successfully find the class

**Update:**

Another solution that you can use that avoids reflection is using the reified generic type's constructor.

Here's how you get its constructor:

```
inline fun <reified VH: CustomClass> myMethod()  {

      val customClassConstructor =  VH::class.constructors.first()
 }
```

This is how you instantiate the reified generic type using its constructor:

```
customClassConstructor.call(constructorData)
```

Comment: How is this different from your `create` method? You still can't call this with a generic type.

Comment: Class constructors can't be declared inline like a function so you would have to pass the reified parameter it using a separate method or some other method(s) if it's possible to do so. However, constructors can have strings as parameters. This means that a class can have a generic bound  that it can instantiate if it was given the generic type's class name as a constructor parameter

Comment: In that case, it seems simpler to just pass in the constructor of the generic type, instead of it's name.

Comment: That does seem like it could be a better solution. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Unless the generic type is reified it disappears during runtime, making you unable to create an instance.

Your example of the reified function `create()` works, but a reified type must be resolved during compilation, so standard generic types cannot be entered as a reified type.

Example of reified "class generating":

```
inline fun <reified VH : Any> generateClass(): RecyclerView.Adapter {
    return object : RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {
        override fun onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position) {
            // Do implementation...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I make it reified? I am trying to make it so that a method can be given a particular type so it can then make that type available later. An example of this would be the `RecyleView.Adapter<RecylerView.ViewHolder>` class as it allows you to implement it like this: `RecylerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>` which in turn then generates methods that use the MyCustomViewHolder type.

Comment: Added how you can "generate" classes using reified generics. If you need to specialize behavior for a given class you need to either use an interface instead of `Any` or provide extension functions that can be used to implement the operation.

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to be compiling at the moment. Do you think think that there might be a cleaner solution using reflection though?